# Multiple deployment approval at once

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a possibility to approve the multiple release deployment at one click. We have 30+ pipelines for release and its very difficult to approve each pipeline individually. It would be great if there is a option to include one approval or one click approve button which will approve all 30 CD pipelines.

Comment: There is no "bulk approve" feature in Azure DevOps to do what you are doing. There are some options to achieve this, but it would greatly depend on what your pipelines are doing and why you need over 30 of them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have 30+ microservices to be deployed and for specific environment we have set the approval part. Client wants to approve the deployments at one click rather going to all the pipelines and doing it.

Comment: Are all 30+ microservices changing at once? If so, I would consider consolidating into a single release pipeline which would give you the on click option your client wants. You can also parallel the deploy so that way multiple services are going to a single environment.

Comment: We need 30+ deployment based on the requirement and it cant be modified/changed. Only option for me is to wait till Azure implement that option in devops.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possibility to approve the multiple release deployment at
>   one click.

For this demand , I am afraid it is currently not support in azure devops , each pipeline can only be approved separately.

If you really need this feature ,you could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) , which is our main forum for product suggestions.Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion.